# Can I import a loop into StudioTrack (iPad)

Tags: ipad

The iPad App StudioTrack comes with a dozen or so options for a drum back beat (see below). Can I use AudioPaste to import a new backbeat? I have been able to import a drum loop but it only plays back once.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hello this is Daniel from Sonoma Wire Works. You can not add a drum beat to play as one of our metronome backbeats, but you can import a drumloop on a track and loop it as many times you would like using AudioPaste. When you copy from an AudioCopy enabled app and then paste into StudioTrack, you will be asked how many times you would like that loop to repeat. Let us know if you have any other questions! support@sonomawireworks.com